# Indexing CSV file contents in Python

Tags: python, indexing, full-text-indexing, whoosh

I have a very large CSV file contaning only two fields (id,url). I want to do some indexing on the url field with python, I know that there are some tools like Whoosh or Pylucene. but I can't get the examples to work. can someone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by indexing?

Answer (score 1):

PyLucene is very easy to work with, but as you haven't posted your example i am not sure what problem you are facing.

Alternatively when you have only key:value type of data, may be better than Pylucene would be DB like  [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html)(python bindings [pybsddb](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm)). It will work like python dictionary and should be more or as fast as lucene, you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

file.csv contents:

```
a,b
d,f
g,h
```

Python script that loads it all into one giant dictionary:

```
#Python 3.1
giant_dict = {id.strip(): url.strip() for id, url in (line.split(',') for line in open('file.csv', 'r'))}

print(giant_dict)
{'a': 'b', 'd': 'f', 'g': 'h'}
```

Comment: Dear lord, why are you parsing it yourself instead of using the CSV module??

Comment: the problem is that this file will be more than 5GB. so I cannot load it into memory at once!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can read file line by line with this: for line in open('file.csv'). Also, why not just get 9GB or RAM installed?

Comment: The urls of this larg file should be compare with another large file,and for faster access i need to do some indexing on.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. What if there is a match? What if there is no match? Describe the whole thing please. Indexing is no silver bullet.

Comment: @Hossein: Please add new facts to the question -- do not add new facts as comments to an answer.